# iOS6: understanding device logs

Tags: ios6, crash-reports

I recently switched to iOS6 and took a look at the device logs (i was looking for some `jettisoned`, trying to find out if my app was killed for memory usage).

This part is similar to the iOS5 logs

```
Incident Identifier: <identifier>
CrashReporter Key:   <key>
Hardware Model:      iPhoneX,Y
OS Version:          iPhone OS 6.1 (10B144)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0:<...>
Date:                2013-02-08 10:27:05 +0100
Time since snapshot: XX ms

Free pages:        945
Active pages:      6629
Inactive pages:    3486
Throttled pages:   87427
Purgeable pages:   1747
Wired pages:       30547
Largest process:   <process name>
```

The following part is not.
In iOS5 the column were named `Name`, `UUID`, `Count`, `resident pages`, but in iOS6...

```
Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max       [reason]          (state)

           name <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>         2834             2834      [highwater]     (daemon) (idle)
           name <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>         2047             2047         [vm]         (suspended)
```

Could someone please explain me what `rpages`, `recent_max` and `[reason]` mean?

And: `(daemon)`, `(idle)` and `(suspended)` are easy to understand, but what does `[highwater]` and `[vm]` mean? I have tried to search in the documentation, but i could not find a single hint...